# Easy looking hard homogenious inequality

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, real-numbers

For non negative $a,b,c$ $27{(a+b)}^{2}{(b+c)}^{2}{(c+a)}^{2}\ge64abc{(a+b+c)}^3$

I've tried to open the brackets but I didn't see how to proceed.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we prove: $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geqslant \frac{8}{9} (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$$
After full expanding$,$ it's $$a(b^2+c^2)+b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2) \geqslant 6abc$$
But it's true by AM-GM$:$ $$a(b^2+c^2) \geqslant 2abc,..$$
So we prove the stronger$:$ $$27\Big[\frac{8}{9} (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\Big]^2\geqslant 64abc(a+b+c)^3$$
After divide both side for $\frac{64}{3} (a+b+c)^2,$ it is equivalent to$:$ $$a^2b^2 +b^2 c^2 +c^2 a^2 \geqslant abc(a+b+c)$$
Which is follow by AM-GM again$:$ $$\frac{1}{2}(a^2 b^2 +b^2 c^2 )\geqslant ab^2 c,..$$
Equality holds when $a=b=c.$ Done $\square$

Comment: Your solution can be expressed in the pqr method: The inequality is written as $27(pq-r)^2 \ge 64rp^3$. Since $pq \ge 9r$ (it is known in the pqr method),
it suffices to prove that $27(pq - pq/9)^2 \ge 64 rp^3$ or $\frac{64}{3}p^2(q^2-3pr)\ge 0$.
Since $q^2\ge 3pr$ (it is known in the pqr method), it is true.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, I also like pqr method. But in some cases, degree of r is high. So I think it's hard.

Comment: You are right. pqr method can be very difficult if the simple (p,q,r) relations  (e.g, $q^2\ge 3pr$, $p^3 +9r \ge 4pq$) are not enough

Comment: @RiverLi I ussualy use Schur Degree 3, 4 (in pqr's form), $p^2\geqslant 3q,q^2 \geqslant 3pr,(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \geqslant 0..$Sometimes SOS is better to solve.

Comment: Usually, if we have to use $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 0$ in pqr method, the inequality is quite complicated.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, and $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \geqslant 0$ is strong!

Comment: @RiverLi you use a crack in Maple or buy license?

Comment: I ve already solved the problem, but my solution is very messy and long, yours however is imo elegant gj

Comment: @pedrofromitaly What do you mean about "imo elegant gj"? I found it is shortest and nature in my three solution.

Comment: @pedrofromitaly Can you show us your solution? This is one of the ways you can get your question reopened, and there are other ways listed in [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).